# Content goes out of div

Tags: html, css

Really can't figure out what's wrong with it, but all the content I add into div, goes out of it, just like it's not in it.

Check it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au5Jf/27/)!

HTML___

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                TEXT GOES OUTSIDE OF DIV :'((
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS___

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px; /*just to see the div*/
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your floats:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                TEXT NOW APPEARS INSIDE DIV :)
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because you've floated your logo, any content following it will wrap around it. Which is what is causing the effect you're seeing.

Comment: Cheers mate! Works perfectly now :)

Comment: You may want to consider using the ::after pseudo selector to clear the float instead of adding an empty HTML element: http://jsfiddle.net/NMbSd/

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `#header` div to restore the expected behavior:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/au5Jf/31/)**

Floating the child essentially removes it from the flow and the parent collapses. Adding the overflow rule gives you the behavior you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd urge you to use flex. It's quite robust and lets you create any kind of layout you want without any issues really. I've added a menu to the right hand side just to illustrate your logo in actual context.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                TEXT GOES OUTSIDE OF DIV :'((
            </div>
            
             <div id="content-menu">
                 <div id="menu">
                   <a href="#">Home</a>
                   <a href="#">Contact</a>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Corresponding CSS:

```
/* CSS */
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.2em auto;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px; /*just to see the div*/
    display: flex;
}

#logo { flex: 1; }

#content-menu { flex: 4;}

#menu { display: flex; }

#menu > a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  flex: 1;
}
```